# AngularJS: Ideas for keeping DRY when calling REST and producing easy readable code, store endpoints in a js object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, restangular

I have been hacking away and currently have quite a few controllers that are calling my backend services, currently I have entered the endpoints directly into the controllers and the URls are stored as string literals.

I can't help thinking its just not right, anyone have any good ideas for tidying up the code, should i stored my endpoints in a js object as key value pairs ?

I am currently using restangular which i am injecting into each controller, is this the correct way of doing it, i could abstract this away into a service but what would I gain from this.

Currently i have my restangular call which accepts 2 functions, 1 for the success and 1 for the fail.

Does anyone have any examples or seen a nice way of doing this sort of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Me and my colleagues use Restangular and a modular approach, passing in the controller name to the module, where a Restangular call is made, meaning we don't tend to repeat ourselves.

Why not have a similar approach and build in a mechanism to work out the controller by convention or from a persisted place (DB/Memory/etc)?

Here is a snippet of what we do in our modules:
On app start:

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(config.apiBaseUrl);
```

Then in the controller for the module (Each module has its own Controller):

```
Restangular.one(this.module.ControllerName, itemCode).get({token: authService.getToken()})
    .then(
        function(event) { 
            $scope.entity = event;
        },
        function(event) { 
            //Bad things went down.
            console.log(event); 
        }
    );
```

The above ControllerName is passed into the controller when it is constructed, it refers to the backend WebAPI controller

At the start of the app, we connect to our WebAPI backend and pull down a list of modules and their respective controllers, which is used to build the modules as shown above.

Once we are happy with the project we have going on, my colleagues and I will publish our framework to Github to demonstrate some of the concepts mentioned above, will update this answer when we get around to it :)